# How to style widget in two columns?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

Can someone guide me on how can I style "**archive widget**"
to show two columns (as in image below)?

[image: archive widget showing two columns]

I am new to wordpress and really don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: by default it shows me items in list form vertically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i designed my own widget something like

in my sidebar.php file by spliting categories data into two columns and then somewhere in page its stlying depending upon this data.

```
<?php       
 $catArray = explode("</li>",wp_list_categories('title_li=&echo=0&depth=1'));
 $catCount = count($catArray) - 1;
 $catColumns = round($catCount / 2);

 for ($i=0;$i<$catCount;$i++) {
  if ($i<$catColumns){
   $catLeft = $catLeft.''.$catArray[$i].'</li>';
          }
  elseif ($i>=$catColumns){
   $catRight = $catRight.''.$catArray[$i].'</li>';
   }  
 };
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only been using wordpress for a few months, but it seems that there's two parts to your problem -

First I would structure your two columns in a 2-column table. Secondly, as it's possible to replace wordpress functions, I would find the function that returns the archive links (probably returning them in a list of some sort). Try modifying this function to return the archived links in the above table structure. It would probably require abit of planning to figure what months you want displayed in each columns or row, but it shouldn't be too hard). This should return straight to your .php file and it should (in theory work) :)

Again, I've only started using wordpress a few months ago, but this is what I would attempt.